# Read an asp page, error 401 unaothorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

Trying to read an intranet asp page, to get all the HTML code, as I need to search for stuff within that.
I can get outside pages to load the html code into a string but not intranet pages, I get error 401 unauthorized.
This works fine for outside pages:

```
    HttpWebRequest webreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://site/main.asp");
        webreq.Method = "GET";
        webreq.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        WebResponse webres = webreq.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webres.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        webres.Close();
```

This still does not work (not for intranet site at least) other sites is fine. Can anyone see why?

How to fix that issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add credentials to your web client. You are getting a 401 on intranet pages because your web client is not authenticating itself.

Comment: Well I had used System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; in the past but its not doing it now - its been a while since I used .net